# v:page don't want show custom pages TYPO3 9.5.19 VHS: 6.0.3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

```
           <v:menu
                    levels="3"
                    excludePages="{settings.menuExclude}"
                    as="menu"
                    expandAll="TRUE"
                    classActive="is-active"
                    >
                                <li class="menu-item">
                                <f:link.typolink parameter="{item.link}"  class="{item.class}">
                                    {item.linktext ->f:format.raw()}
                                </f:link.typolink>
                                </li>
  </v:menu>
```

I add a custom page like described here:  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/PageTypes/Index.html

But `v:menu` don't want/show to render the page in menu. Settings doctypes deprecated, so how I can add custom pagetype in my menu??

Comment: what about using a menuprocessor and use a partial to render it completely on your own?

Comment: Yer, thx I know different ways to do that. Already did with TMENU typoscript tobject. But my question about v:menu and VHS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot from the hip: make sure your `doktype` value for the custom page type is a value below 199, as everything above this is considered "unlinkable" by TYPO3. VHS will not impose any limits so this all depends on which `doktype` values are considered valid by TYPO3 itself.

Comment: You totally right, it was my problem. Thx for info will know now about that.